# jQuery hide Div when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

this is the Code for my Navigation Bar (ignore the .hide() spam)

```
  function test(){
    var tabsNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent');
    var selectorNewAnim = $('#navbarSupportedContent').find('li').length;
    var activeItemNewAnim = tabsNewAnim.find('.active');
    var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = activeItemNewAnim.innerHeight();
    var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = activeItemNewAnim.innerWidth();
    var itemPosNewAnimTop = activeItemNewAnim.position();
    var itemPosNewAnimLeft = activeItemNewAnim.position();
    $(".hori-selector").css({
        "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px",
        "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
        "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
        "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
    });
    $("#navbarSupportedContent").on("click","li",function(e){
        $('#navbarSupportedContent ul li').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var activeWidthNewAnimHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
        var activeWidthNewAnimWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
        var itemPosNewAnimTop = $(this).position();
        var itemPosNewAnimLeft = $(this).position();
        $(".hori-selector").css({
            "top":itemPosNewAnimTop.top + "px",
            "left":itemPosNewAnimLeft.left + "px",
            "height": activeWidthNewAnimHeight + "px",
            "width": activeWidthNewAnimWidth + "px"
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ test(); });
      $("#toggle1").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").show("slow");
     $("#panel2").hide();
      $("#panel3").hide();
       $("#panel4").hide();
        $("#panel5").hide();
  });

      $("#toggle2").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").hide()
     $("#panel2").show("slow");
      $("#panel3").hide();
       $("#panel4").hide();
        $("#panel5").hide();
  });

      $("#toggle3").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").hide()
     $("#panel2").hide()
      $("#panel3").show("slow");
       $("#panel4").hide();
        $("#panel5").hide();
  });

      $("#toggle4").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").hide()
     $("#panel2").hide()
      $("#panel3").hide()
       $("#panel4").show("slow");
        $("#panel5").hide();
  });

        $("#toggle5").click(function() {
    $("#panel1").hide()
     $("#panel2").hide()
      $("#panel3").hide()
       $("#panel4").hide()
        $("#panel5").show("slow");
  });
});
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ test(); }, 500);
});
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").slideToggle(300);
    setTimeout(function(){ test(); });
});
```

When the page loads I want to hide divs with the id #panel2, #panel3, #panel4...
How can I do this?

Or is it also possible that if the  links lead to a specific id, for example href="#panel4" and I refresh the page, that all divs are hidden except #panel4?

EDIT
The HTML Nav:

```
  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a id="toggle1" class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>My Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a id="toggle2" class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-address-book"></i>Buttons</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="toggle3" class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-clone"></i>Background</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="toggle4" class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Tracking</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="toggle5" class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i>Other</a>
                </li>
```

Comment: You should think about your approach *before* you copy and paste it five times and need to add a "ignore the spam" comment. The moment to stop and think is right after you copy multiple lines of code and right before you paste them the first time.

Comment: No Thomas I have no idea about jQuery

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide them as soon as the DOM finished loading you can use the
`DOMContentLoaded` event.

You also need to check if the `DOMContentLoaded` event hasn't fired before your code execution. You can do that with the `document.readyState`

With jQuery you have the `.hide()` method to hide elements.

You can also show keep the anchor used in your url visible. You can  get it with `window.location.href` and a regex.

```js
const regex = /#.*/;
const url = window.location.href;
const anchor = url.match(regex)[0]

if(document.readyState === "complete") {
    $("#panel2, #panel3, #panel4").hide();
    $(anchor).show();
}else{
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        $("#panel2, #panel3, #panel4").hide();
        $(anchor).show();
    });
}
```

However, you might have a small delay where you see the elements.

Comment: Great. Thank you! Let's say the toggle2 button leads to the ID #panel2 (href="#panel2"). So the URL also contains #panel2

And when I refresh the page, I want all divs to be hidden except #panel2.

So that when you refresh the page you are still at the respective ID. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I edited my answer for the anchor question. Didn't test it so tell me if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately not. For example I pressed toggle2 link that goes to #panel2 and then refresh the page, it still shows #panel1

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: No it doesnt, I dont even see errors